# Display Toast notification from Application

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, toast

I have a desktop application running on windows and I want it to display notification exactly as the built in windows toast notification like this figure:

[image: Toast Notifcation in windows]

To be able to use WinRT and using the name space Windows.UI.Notification, I had modified the project file which is ProjectName.clsproj to target windows 8 platform like this

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>8.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
```

is it possible to make the project target more than one version of windows 
I mean I want my application to be able to run on windows 8, 8.1 and 10

Comment: Have you tried [Windows Toast Notifications with C#](https://github.com/noxad/windows-toast-notifications)?

Comment: yes i tried it , and worked successfully